# Find files in git that have entry in .editorconfig

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, xargs

I want to find all of the files in git that have some extensions. The list of extensions is generated from my .editorconfig file.

Say I have a list of file extensions such as:

```
.css
.html
.java
.js
```

(This is generated from .editorconfig)

I would like to find all of the files tracked by git that have these extensions.

At the moment, I have this command:

```
grep -oE "\.[a-z0-9]+" .editorconfig | xargs -I{} grep {} <(git ls-files)
```

The output is :

```
src/main/site/src/App.css
src/main/site/src/index.css
```

The command currently isn't running grep for each file extension, only the first one. What's wrong with the command? I want this to be a single command, without creating any intermediate files.

edit:
The reason I generate the list of files from .editorconfig is because I want to check the code styles of each file generated by this command, and more files may be added to the config in the future, so I would like some future-proofing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
grep -oE "\.[a-z0-9]+" .editorconfig | xargs -I{} grep {} <(git ls-files)
```

seems weird : you ask `xargs` to take as an input a pipe from `grep` and also from `(git ls-files)`. A little trial : `echo a | cat <(echo b)` indicates the `echo b` wins ! In your example, `git ls-files` seems to win which is consistive.

Unfortunately, xargs has only one standard input and you can only search one regex (excepted with `-e` and `-f` options).

The best things seems to create a regexfile from your `.editorconfig` file and launch `git ls-files | grep -f regexfile

Comment: The part `<(git ls-files)` is supposed to be piped into the stdin of grep, but I suppose its being sent to xargs

Comment: `cat <(echo a b)|xargs echo` works as intended ! But if you use `xargs grep`, warning, grep use the first argument as a regex, and the following as files to open and grep. As I have written above (last edition), you need `-e` or `-f` options to make `grep` search multiple regex.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Frédéric Loyer's answer I've solved my problem, but with the compromise of having to create an intermediate file.

I could either of these commands

```
grep -oE "\.[a-z0-9]+" .editorconfig > out && git ls-files | grep -f out && rm out
```

```
git ls-files > out && grep -oE "\.[a-z0-9]+" .editorconfig | xargs -I{} grep {} out && rm out
```

and they would have more or less the desired effect, but some unwanted files were slipping through.

I realised that the file extensions that were generated from `.editorconfig` were being used as patterns for grep again, so the leading period had to be escaped, resulting in the following command:

```
grep -oE "\.[a-z0-9]+" .editorconfig | xargs -I{} echo "\{}" > out && git ls-files | grep -f out && rm out
```

Slightly shorter alternative using sed:

```
grep -oE "\.[a-z0-9]+" .editorconfig | sed 's/^/\\/' > out && git ls-files | grep -f out && rm out
```